# WPF not recognizing custom Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf

I have built a class library and for some reason when I put it in the `Using Molo.Core.Reference` at the top of the C# file, I still have to type the entire path vs typing just `Reference.{public}` in the code. See example below.

```
using NLog;
using Molo.Core.Reference;
using System;
```

...

```
Process.Start(Molo.Core.Reference.Ground.logSite);
log.Info("Started " + content + ". It will be started externally.");
```

In VS2015 the Molo.Core.Reference is greyed out like it's not being used. When I type `Reference` it will not appear in the Inteli-sense. The only thing that appears is when I type `Molo`

Comment: I believe including `Molo.Core.Reference` means you can use what is contained inside of it. IE `Ground.logSite` instead of `Reference.Ground.logSite`

Comment: Pulling `Ground.logSite` pulls up another folder that is labeled `Ground` that's in the project. Should I rename the .dll folder name?

Comment: Sounds like you have a namespace conflict then. Perhaps you can use an alias? I've never had to use it, but supposedly, it's `using myAlias = Molo.Core.Reference`

Comment: @Tom that worked! If you post that as an answer, I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a namespace conflict. You have two namespaces that have the same name. Or some sub-namespace is conflicting with another one. You can use an `alias` with your `using` to avoid the conflict. Then reference your library from the `alias`.

```
using myAlias = Molo.Core.Reference;
// ....
myAlias.Ground.logSite;
```